# dom.byId returns undefined after the element has been added

Tags: javascript, dojo

Ive got a function that is adding a div as a child to a dijit/layout/conentpane.  The problem I'm having is that after I add this div I can't reference it by using dom.byId:  The function that creates this div is called from a click event of a menuitem:

the menu item:

```
<div id="miLMWS" data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem" data-dojo-props="onClick:function(){SetPage('LMWS');}">Watershed</div>
```

the onclick function (SetPage):

```
....

function (dom, parser, registry, ready, WatershedMap, OWOWMapGallery) {
            window.SetPage = function (pg) {
                //set the page depending on the menu item clicked
                ClearWidget();//destroys previous widget deleting the div
                AddToolDiv();//add the div
                switch (pg) {
                    case 'LMWS':
                        var test = dom.byId("tool"); //this is undefined
                        //WS = new WatershedMap({}, "tool");
                        break;
                }
            };
...
```

The addDivFunction:

```
function AddToolDiv() {
     //add page div (node where template will be placed in
     var tool = document.createElement("div");
     tool.setAttribute("id", "tool");
     var ContentContainer = registry.byId("MainContent");
      ContentContainer.set("MainContent", tool);
      var test = dom.byId("tool");//this is undefined
 }
```

Each time a menu item is clicked a new custom widget gets loaded into the tool div. (There is a function ClearWidget that destroys the old widget and the tool div)  I'm thinking that maybe this has something to do with calling the function from the onClick event?  When I call the AddToolDiv when the page first loads the test variable correctly refers to the tool div.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `byId` function will search the DOM for an element with the given id. If your tool element hasn't actually been inserted into the DOM when you call `byId`, you will get undefined.

The code you have shown never actually inserts the tool element into the DOM, it only passes it to the `ContentContainer.set("MainContent", tool)` call. Be sure to check that this call actually inserts the tool element into the DOM immediately. Is ContentConainer itself inserted into the DOM when you call `byId`?

Comment: Thanks -- this helps me to understand what might be going on.  Funny thing is I've used the exact same methodology on a tree click event and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these things

`var test = dom.byId("tool",ContentContainer.domNode);`

else you can hold the reference of this dom directly
 `this.tool = document.createElement("div");`

else use domconstruct api provided in dojo

Comment: Thanks I was able to get the reference using this.tool = document.createElement("div");  
Im now trying to use it when I create my new widget:
WS = new WatershedMap({}, this.tool);
but I'm getting cannot read property id of null?

Comment: can you provide your updated code or can you set up something in jsfiddle, most likely it will be a scope issue, where you're creating your div and where you're creating your widget, one more thing instead of using document.createelement try using domconstruct.create. Please provide more information

Comment: I've used: this.tool = domConstruct.create("div");
and am getting the same result. I'll see if I can get something set up on jsfiddle

Thank You

Comment: @pvitt you have to provide .domNode while you're creating the widget WS = new WatershedMap({}, this.tool.domNode); hope this helps

Comment: I finally figured this out. The problem was in the AddToolDiv function

the line:
ContentContainer.set("MainContent", tool);

needed to be:
ContentContainer.set("content", tool);

I wasnt adding my tool div to the ContentContainer

Thanks for all the help -- sorry it was something so silly